R: Multiple Dropdown Menus
I made the following network in R:
library(igraph)
library(reshape2)

north_american_cities <- c("New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Houston", "Phoenix")
european_cities <- c("London", "Berlin", "Madrid", "Rome", "Paris")
asian_cities <- c("Tokyo", "Delhi", "Shanghai", "Beijing", "Mumbai")

n <- 30

set.seed(123) 

na_cities_sample <- sample(north_american_cities, n, replace = TRUE)
eu_cities_sample <- sample(european_cities, n, replace = TRUE)
as_cities_sample <- sample(asian_cities, n, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(NorthAmerica = na_cities_sample,
                 Europe = eu_cities_sample,
                 Asia = as_cities_sample,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]

edges_df <- data.frame(from = c(df$NorthAmerica, df$Europe),
                       to = c(df$Europe, df$Asia))

edge_list <- as.matrix(edges_df)

g <- graph_from_edgelist(edge_list, directed = TRUE)
plot(g, vertex.size=10, vertex.label.cex=0.8, edge.arrow.size=0.5)


I then added a single drop down menu for navigation using visNetwork:
    library(visNetwork)
nodes_df <- data.frame(id = unique(c(df$NorthAmerica, df$Europe, df$Asia)), 
                       group = c(rep("North America", length(unique(df$NorthAmerica))),
                                 rep("Europe", length(unique(df$Europe))),
                                 rep("Asia", length(unique(df$Asia)))))

edges_df <- data.frame(from = c(df$NorthAmerica, df$Europe),
                       to = c(df$Europe, df$Asia))

colors <- c('North America' = 'red', 'Europe' = 'green', 'Asia' = 'blue')

visNetwork(nodes_df, edges_df) %>%   
    visNodes(color = list(background = colors[nodes_df$group])) %>%
    visEdges(arrows = 'to') %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
    visInteraction(navigation = "zoom") %>%
    visInteraction(navigation = "drag")


My Question: I am trying to modify the above code to create 3 dropdown menus, that would allow someone to select a north american city and see all possible journeys that can be taken - then to click on a european city to further narrow it down:

I tried searching for examples online, but it seems like visNetwork in R might not allow this option of multiple dropdowns.

I tried to see if there might be anything possible using javascript events
I found some options involving R Shiny, e.g. R - state of the art performance of visNetwork vs networkd3 in a Shiny app (2017)

But I am not sure how to implement either of these.
Can someone please show me how I might be able to add these 3 dropdowns in R?
Thanks!

and you want that in Java? Or how is this question related to the Java programming language? (in Java: var menu1 = new JComboBox(...); var menu2 = ...; panel.add(menu1); panel.add(menu2); ...)

You could try to add the dropdowns as follows:
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)
library(igraph)

# Data Preparation
north_american_cities <- c("New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Houston", "Phoenix")
european_cities <- c("London", "Berlin", "Madrid", "Rome", "Paris")
asian_cities <- c("Tokyo", "Delhi", "Shanghai", "Beijing", "Mumbai")

n <- 30
set.seed(123)

na_cities_sample <- sample(north_american_cities, n, replace = TRUE)
eu_cities_sample <- sample(european_cities, n, replace = TRUE)
as_cities_sample <- sample(asian_cities, n, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(NorthAmerica = na_cities_sample,
                 Europe = eu_cities_sample,
                 Asia = as_cities_sample,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]

edges_df <- data.frame(from = c(df$NorthAmerica, df$Europe),
                       to = c(df$Europe, df$Asia))

edge_list <- as.matrix(edges_df)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(edge_list, directed = TRUE)

nodes_df <- data.frame(id = unique(c(df$NorthAmerica, df$Europe, df$Asia)), 
                       group = c(rep("North America", length(unique(df$NorthAmerica))),
                                 rep("Europe", length(unique(df$Europe))),
                                 rep("Asia", length(unique(df$Asia)))))

edges_df <- data.frame(from = c(df$NorthAmerica, df$Europe),
                       to = c(df$Europe, df$Asia))

colors <- c('North America' = 'red', 'Europe' = 'green', 'Asia' = 'blue')

# Shiny App
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("City Network Visualization"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("na_city", "Select North American City:", choices = north_american_cities),
      selectInput("eu_city", "Select European City:", choices = european_cities),
      selectInput("as_city", "Select Asian City:", choices = asian_cities)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      visNetworkOutput("network")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered_edges <- reactive({
    edges_df %>%
      filter(from %in% c(input$na_city, input$eu_city) | to %in% c(input$eu_city, input$as_city))
  })
  
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes_df, filtered_edges()) %>%   
      visNodes(color = list(background = colors[nodes_df$group])) %>%
      visEdges(arrows = 'to') %>%
      visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
      visInteraction(navigation = "zoom") %>%
      visInteraction(navigation = "drag")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

This might need some tinkering for your use-case, but it might be a good starting point.
